# Funny thing in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Looking into ActiveRecord source at file `active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb`, I found something strange(code edited for brevity)

```
    def second
      find_nth(:second, offset_value ? offset_value + 1 : 1)
    end

    def second!
      second or raise RecordNotFound
    end

    def third
      find_nth(:third, offset_value ? offset_value + 2 : 2)
    end

    def third!
      third or raise RecordNotFound
    end

    def fourth
      find_nth(:fourth, offset_value ? offset_value + 3 : 3)
    end

    def fourth!
      fourth or raise RecordNotFound
    end

    def fifth
      find_nth(:fifth, offset_value ? offset_value + 4 : 4)
    end

    def fifth!
      fifth or raise RecordNotFound
    end

    def forty_two
      find_nth(:forty_two, offset_value ? offset_value + 41 : 41)
    end

    def forty_two!
      forty_two or raise RecordNotFound
    end
```

I can understand the first and last methods but second, third, fourth, so on do not   make much sense. Moreover, there is a jump from fifth to forty-second record. You can keep going with writing sugar methods for selecting a specifically positioned record.

Could there be any specific reason for this?

Comment: `forty_two` is a kind of joke.

Comment: Hahaha nice finding @Norman

Comment: http://www.quora.com/Why-is-Array-forty_two-called-the-reddit-in-Ruby-on-Rails

Comment: DHH at first added [#second through #tenth](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/22af62cf486721ee2e45bb720c42ac2f4121faf4) but [reduced the number of literal aliases](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e50530ca3ab5db53ebc74314c54b62b91b932389) later on

Comment: You don't need to cite the source code. It only makes your question unclear. Just mention the methods.

Comment: Nice catch .. Norman.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a science fiction reference to [42 being revealed as the answer to life, the universe and everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29) in [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)

Anytime an arbitary number that's not too large can be chosen, a lot of scifi fans opt for `42`